# NO SE INSTALA VUETIFY

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Tengo un problema en cuanto a la instalación de vuetify, y es que simplemente no se instala. Cuando utilizo el comando "vue add vuetify", aparece el mensaje como si se estuviese instalando, pero no se instala [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

solo se queda como aparece en la imagen he esperado mas de una hora, cuando este proceso por lo general, no debería demorar mas de 2 minutos.
Intente este proceso en 2 IDE´s(VsCode,Webstorm) y en todos tiene el mismo resultado.

Agradecería pudiesen ayudarme

Comment: Por favor añade más detalles acerca de qué tecnologías estás usando y también asegúrate haber leído completamente [la documentación](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/), puede ser un error de versiones o incluso que simplemente se trabó tu consola.

Comment: Si, lei completamente la documentación, estoy utilizando NodeJs (npm) desde Windows. Ya intente instalar vuetify con el comando vue add vuetify , e instalar desde vue ui,  pero en los 2 casos me ocurre lo mismo (no carga la instalación). He probado reinstalando NodeJs y Vue/cli, pero esto tampoco fue la solución.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Vue estás usando? La documentación en su página inicial nos dice "When creating a new project, please ensure you selected Vue 2 from the Vue CLI prompts, or that you are installing to an existing Vue 2 project.". Recuerda que vuetify aún no soporta Vue 3. Y por favor los detalles menciónalos en la pregunta, no en los comentarios :) 
Suerte